# Using individual Accounts and Microsoft.Identity.Web for Authentication in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-identity, openid-connect, identity, dotnetopenauth, microsoft.identity.web

With AzureAD.UI being deprecated I wanted to build a web app that uses individual accounts and `Microsoft.Identity.Web` for authentication. I have tried multiple ways and twice thought I had it, just to be given an error

> Error loading external login information

after completing the Azure AD login.

I started with a new project using individual accounts authentication type in Visual Studio 2022.

Added `Microsoft.Identity.Web` nuget package

Here is my `Program.cs`:

```
using AuthTest.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    // Set the name of the claim in the JWT token that represents the user's display name
    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Here is my `appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-AuthTest;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
    "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "Domain": "**********",
        "TenantId": "***********",
        "ClientId": "****************",
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
        "ClientSecret": "******************",
        "ClientCertificates": []
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Does anyone see or know what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer, posting it in case someone stumbles across this also.

```
using AuthTest.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration, cookieScheme: null);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

"cookieScheme: null" seems to be what resolved the issue.

Found details of the issue here
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/133